# How to make containerd forward logs to journald

Tags: docker, kubernetes, syslog, containerd, systemd-journald

I am  using k8s where I am using containerd as CRI.

How to make containerd forward logs to journald ?

Which and what configuration i must do ?

Answer (score 1):

This is alerady the case, nothing to do.
You can get the logs using:

journalctl -u containerd